# How to install mist (browser) and wallet on Linux Ubuntu?

Tags: mist, ubuntu, linux

I am somewhat new to Linux and have been having difficulty installing Mist. I tried using this script https://gist.github.com/tgerring/d4ab3f1672ed91a53c6c to no avail. It usually goes wrong around line 11. I am trying to download Mist 8.10 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 7):

The release download page is [here](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases)

Download the *.deb (Debian) file, e.g. Ethereum-Wallet-linux64-0-9-0.deb

Then do:

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo dpkg -i Ethereum-Wallet-linux64-0-9-0.deb
```

Comment: I know I have been to the release page, downloaded the most recent versions of everything and tried to follow the script but it does not work.

Comment: What error do you get? @tmarcon

Comment: Another way is to download the .zip version. You can unpack it with unzip Ethereum-Wallet-linux64-0-9-2.zip and then change into the folder linux-unpacked and execute the program ethereumwallet.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too.

That worked fine for me:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all Ethereum-Wallet-linux32-0-8-7.deb
```

In case that doesn't work you can try here https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/1418

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues too and used the `--force-all` option to install Ethereum-Wallet. The wallet installed but with a catch:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i --force-all Ethereum-Wallet-linux64-0-9-3.deb 
...
...
dpkg: ethereumwallet: dependency problems, but configuring anyway as you requested: ethereumwallet depends on libappindicator1.
```

So had to attend to that issue:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libappindicator1
...
...
Conflicts: libappindicator1 but 12.10.1+16.04.20170215-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
$ sudo apt-get -f install
...
...
$ ethereumwallet --version

[2018-02-21 20:33:34.554] [INFO] main - 0.9.3
```